# Show that an inverse image $F^{-1}$ is an isometric bijection, if $F$ is an isometric bijection.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, isometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces. In order to show the result, we would need to show that $\Vert F^{-1}(y)\Vert_X = \Vert y \Vert_Y$ for all $y \in Y$. My intuition tells me that bijectivity alone should suffice to prove this, as it implies that
$$
F(F^{-1}(y)) = y
\quad\text{and}\quad
F^{-1}(F(x)) = x
$$
for all $y \in Y$ and $x \in X$. Then taking the norm of $y = F(x) \in Y$ results in
$$
\Vert y \Vert_Y = \Vert F(x) \Vert_Y = \Vert F(F^{-1}(y)) \Vert_Y = \Vert F^{-1}(y) \Vert_X
$$
by the isometricity of $F$, where we have denoted $x = F^{-1}(y)$. Is this sufficient to conclude the proof?

Comment: Is $F$ linear? In general, isometries of normed *real* linear spaces are *affine* maps, but even that is not immediate.

Comment: @Gae.S. Well, as we a discussing sequence and function spaces in a linear setting, as in thus far we have thought of them as vector spaces, then I would assume so.

Comment: *Isometry*, per se, denotes a function $f:(X,d_X)\to (Y,d_Y)$ between metric spaces such that $d_Y(f(a),f(b))=d_X(a,b)$ for all $a,b$. For instance, I don't see a reason why the non-$\Bbb C$-affine isometry $z\mapsto \overline z$ of the $\Bbb C$-normed space $\Bbb C$ shouldn't be called isometry.